# Angular2 :: Some questions about best practices

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

So I'm trying to develop a non-trivial Angular2 application. I've had headaches about UI not updating at times to reflect the application state. I've searched a lot about how to resolve this and I've found advice that I try following but without completely understanding how or why it should be this way. Here, I wanted to ask some questions about a few things I've gathered. Please see this reference code:

**Person.ts**

```
export class Person {
  name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

**DataService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  list: Person[] = [];
  add(person: Person) {
    this.list.push(person);
  }
  edit(person: Person, newName: string) {
    person.name = newName;
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
@Component({
  template: `<div *ngFor="let person of dataService.list">
               {{person.name}}
             <div>
             <button (click)="onClickAdd()">Add</button>`
})
export class MyPage {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
  onClickAdd() {
    // async function to get input from user
    Alert.create({
      inputs: [...],
      buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        handler: (data) => {
          this.dataService.add(new Person(data.name));
        }
      }]
    });
  }
}
```

**And now the questions..**

1. When I call `this.list.push(...)`, the array reference does not change. I've read that the reference should change in order for Angular to detect that something has changed and hence the view should be updated. I've seen that the above code works as well (mostly). Why is that? And more importantly, is it recommended that I do something like this to ensure that the array reference itself changes?

   ```
   add(person: Person) {
     this.list = [person].concat(this.list);
   }
   edit(person: Person, newName: string) {
     person.name = newName;
     this.list = [].concat(this.list);
   }
   ```
2. I've read that `Observables` should be used whenever data is changed asynchronously. Would there be any benefit in changing the implementation like so?

   ```
   export class DataService {
     list: Person[] = [];
     _observableList: BehaviorSubject<Person[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
     get observableList(): Observable<Person[]> { return this.observableList.asObservable() }
     add(person: Person) {
       this.list.push(person);
       this._observableList.next(this.list);
     }
     edit(person: Person, newName: string) {
       person.name = newName;
       this._observableList.next(this.list);
     }
   }

   <div *ngFor="let person of dataService.observableList | async">
     {{person.name}}
   </div>
   ```

Comment: I myself am using the latter method (employing Observables). Not sure about any beneficial effect but just to unify my way of treating data.

Comment: 2 looks fine . .  .

Answer (score 0):

1) The reference does not need to change for angular 2 pick up new elements inside the array. New values can be added to an array and should be detected.

Personally i think to explain angular change detection here would be far too long a topic please read through the below link it works.

[Article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

2) Yes you can use observables and this is the trend that is taking place currently specifically if you use something like RxJS which seems to be 'trending' look it up.